# identifier not found in a class c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "Tree.h"

template <class type>
class loader{
private:
    tree<type> *seq;
    sf::Sprite BG_img;
    sf::Texture texture;
    int seq_c;
    //node<sf::String> cp1;
    //node<sf::String> *temp;
    //declaring text object
    sf::Text text;
    sf::Text sfoption1;
    sf::Text sfoption2;
    sf::Text sfoption3;
    sf::String path;

public:
    loader(){
        seq=NULL;
        seq_c=1;
        //setting text
        text.setCharacterSize(15);
        text.setColor(sf::Color::Black);

        sfoption1.setCharacterSize(15);
        sfoption1.setColor(sf::Color::Black);

        sfoption2.setCharacterSize(15);
        sfoption2.setColor(sf::Color::Black);

        sfoption3.setCharacterSize(15);
        sfoption3.setColor(sf::Color::Black);

        //cp1.setData(1);
        //cp1.setopt1(newnode(temp,1));
    }
    void set_tree(tree<type> *a,int deep,sf::String Root_name="1"){
        seq=a;
        add_data(seq,deep,Root_name);
    }

    void add_data(tree<type> *a, int counter=0, sf::String nama="1"){
        if(counter == 3);
        else {
            a->add(nama);
            counter++;
            add_data(a, counter, nama + ".1");
            add_data(a, counter, nama + ".2");
            add_data(a, counter, nama + ".3");
        }
    }
    int Load_now(sf::String seq='1'){
        path = "Sequence/" + seq +".png";
        texture.loadFromFile(path);
        BG_img.setTexture(texture);

        ifstream ff;
        string data, option1, option2, option3;
        string s_path =  "Sequence/" + seq + ".txt";
        ff.open(s_path, ios::in);
        getline(ff,data);
        getline(ff,option1);
        if(!ff.eof()) getline(ff,option2);
        if(!ff.eof()) getline(ff,option3);
        ff.close();


        //setting text position
        text.setPosition(0,0);
        sfoption1.setPosition(0,1);
        sfoption2.setPosition(0,2);
        sfoption3.setPosition(0,3);

        //passing text
        text.setString(data);
        sfoption1.setString(option1);
        if(option1 == "Main menu") return 0;
        else return 1;
        if(option2 != "") sfoption2.setString(option2);
        if(option3 != "") sfoption3.setString(option3);


    }

    int next(int inp){
        return load_now(seq->get_data(inp));
    }
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &window){
        window.draw(BG_img);
        //draW TO DISPLAY text
        window.draw(text);
        window.draw(sfoption1);
        if(sfoption2 != NULL) window.draw(sfoption2);
        if(sfoption3 != NULL) window.draw(sfoption3);
    }
    void chhose(int x){
    }
};
```

so i have school project and i create this as a header file in c++.
but when i compile this error comes up
"error C3861: 'load_now': identifier not found  line 92".
i don't understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: `Load_now` vs `load_now`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have slightly problem in your code. You have `Load_now`. So,

```
return load_now(seq->get_data(inp));
```

replace by

```
return Load_now(seq->get_data(inp));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `seq->get_data(inp)`return? I think compiler does not determine the data type of `seq->get_data(inp)`.

And `Load_now` not  `load_now`